# Replacing missing "newline" in pre-processed text

Tags: c#, regex

I've inherited a database table of emails where the saved body text has been processed to remove diacritics but this process has also taken out the Environment.Newline characters.  I can write a regular expression to identify this pattern ([.!?.!?]\ {0}\w) as there is no whitespace between the typical end of sentence marker (e.g: .!?) and the start of the next sentence, but I can't see how to then insert a newline between the two characters.

E:g:  "This is the end of the first paragraph.And this is the start of the second.

I want to insert a new line (in this case between "h.A") and wherever this type of pattern occurs. Any help would be appreciated (I use C# .NET 4.5)- I've spent hours with RegExBuddy and can't see how to do it.  Please pardon my ignorance.

Answer (score 0):

First off, I'd consider pushing to obtain the original message instead of resorting to these kinds of measures, as the result won't be perfect.

You can use the regular expression `[\.\!\?]\b`, which is defined as punctuation followed by the start of a word.

Example code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(RestoreNewlines("This is the end of the first paragraph.And this is the start of the second. This is the start of the third."));
    Console.WriteLine(RestoreNewlines("Example of a case.txt where it fails."));
}

private static readonly Regex PunctuationWithoutFollowingWhitespaceRegex = new Regex(@"[\.\!\?]\b");

static string RestoreNewlines(string input)
{
    return PunctuationWithoutFollowingWhitespaceRegex.Replace(input, match => match.Value + Environment.NewLine);
}
```

Output:

```
This is the end of the first paragraph.
And this is the start of the second. This is the start of the third.
Example of a case.
txt where it fails.
```

Comment: Ps, I would have recovered the emails if they had been available: they had been POPped off the server by the tool they used.